# Battery icon not updating

Tags: battery

The battery icon on the panel only changes when I restart or log-out then log back in. For example, my battery is low at 15%, however, the icon indicates its at 79%, which was the percentage when I first booted into the OS.

Comment: well its not an solution ubuntu does good for me but have an issue with elementary then its an bug!!..

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug, and is being tracked and worked on:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power/+bug/1315434

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be as a driver issue. It seems you are using a laptop, and in that case updates drivers should be available for your laptop from the manufacturer's website. Try installing that

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of noob. How do I download the drivers? It seems like they're only windows compatible. I have a lenoxo ideapad flex 15.

Answer (score 0):

Me too had the same issue, Power Indicator didn't update once its booted. Found answer in G+. And it works fine for me. Source [here](https://plus.google.com/+FagnerPinheiroSantos/posts/SNkvwBNHCN4).

Downgrade upower to get it working again.

```
sudo apt-get install upower=0.9.23-2ubuntu1﻿
```

After downgrade, Do this to prevent the package being automatically upgraded.

```
sudo apt-mark hold upower﻿
```